# TapGestureRecognizer in Xamarin.Forms that doesn't intercept the tap

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make 'kiosk-like' functionality in a Xamarin.Forms app, where after a period of no user input, the app performs an action (like going back to an attract screen). I was thinking of putting a BoxView overtop the screen at 0 opacity, attaching a TapGestureRecognizer, and listening for taps to reset the timer. Problem is, the tap is intercepted, and the controls underneath do not receive input. Is there any way to 'pass-through' the tap so that while I'm getting a callback from the user input, I'm not preventing it from being sent to other controls?

Comment: Why not just push a new page on the navigation stack after the period of no use and then pop it on the tap?

Comment: That's not the issue. I need to detect user interaction during use of the app and reset the counter that triggers the new page on the navigation stack.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question